# How do I write a simple melody using the python package mingus and a for cycle?

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to create a list of musical notes using a *for cicle* to detect the last note in the list and use it as starting tone to calculate the interval. I'm using a package called mingus, version 0.6.1, and every time I try to access the list items using `melody[i]` the following message appears. Any help?

```
TypeError: 'Note' object is not subscriptable.
```

Here is the code:

```
import mingus.core.intervals as itv
from mingus.containers import Note

melody = []
note1 = Note("A", 4)
melody.append(note1)

for i in range(3):
    next_note = itv.interval("A", melody[i], 1)    
    melody.append(next_note)

print(melody)
```

Comment: What does the documentation tell you about usage of *itv.interval* ?

Comment: Hey @Codist this is the intervals.interval documentation (I used itv instead of interval):  [code block] mingus.core.intervals.interval(key, start_note, interval)[source]
Return the note found at the interval starting from start_note in the given key.

Raise a KeyError exception if start_note is not a valid note.

Example:

>>> interval('C', 'D', 1)
'E'

Comment: Not knowing this library, this code looks fine. I looked at [the docs](https://bspaans.github.io/python-mingus/doc/wiki/refMingusCoreIntervals.html#mingus.core.intervals.interval) but there are no type hints, so no help there. Please post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: @UmbertoBoldarin Thank you for letting me know where the documentation is but I already knew that. I was rather hoping that **you** would read it. Then you'd know where you've gone wrong

Comment: @wjandrea The lack of type hints is disappointing. However, the code is publicly available and it's clear that the second parameter to the *interval()* function should be a string. The examples in the documentation also show strings being used. Clearly, a Note object is inappropriate - hence the error

Comment: @Codist my bad! You are right, in the documentation of interval() only strings were used as arguments. However, it is not intuitive. Why should I use simple strings when the Note() class exists? Thank you for your answer :)